# PHP Deleting a full folder

Tags: php, linux, delete-file

I have the following function that I am trying to use to delete a full folder but it does not seem to be deleting any ideas or recommendations?

```
public function submit()
{
        $location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/_assets/quote/uploads/';

        $folderName = $this->quote->getCompanyDetails()->companyName;

        $data['companyContact'] = $this->quote->getCompanyDetails()->companyContact;

        $this->load->view('submit',$data);

        $this->quote->removeQuote();

        if(is_dir($location.$folderName) === TRUE)
        {
            $files = array_diff(scandir($location.$folderName), array('.','..'));

            foreach($files as $file)
            {
                Delete(realpath($location.$folderName).'/'. $file);
            }
            return rmdir($location.$folderName);
        }
        else if(is_file($location.$folderName) === TRUE)
        {
            return unlink($location.$folderName);
        }
        return FALSE;
}
```

**Update:**

```
public function submit()
{
        $location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/_assets/quote/uploads/';

        $folderName = $this->quote->getCompanyDetails()->companyName;

        $data['companyContact'] = $this->quote->getCompanyDetails()->companyContact;

        $this->load->view('submit',$data);

        //$this->quote->removeQuote();

        $this->removeFolder();
}

private function removeFolder(){
        $location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/_assets/quote/uploads/';

        $folderName = $this->quote->getCompanyDetails()->companyName;

        foreach(glob($location.$folderName.'/*') as $file)
        {
            if(is_dir($location.$folderName))
            {
                rmdir($location.$folderName);
            }else{
                unlink($location.$folderName);
            }
            rmdir($location.$folderName);
        }
}
```

Comment: do you have permission to delete files on the operating system?

Comment: You call 'Delete' the first time and 'unlink' the second time. Shouldn't that be unlink both times?

Comment: @kingcoyote I found that on here unsure if correct

Comment: Unless you're using a library that defines Delete, it doesn't natively exist in PHP. Try replacing the call to Delete with unlink, which is the actual PHP command to delete a file.

Comment: you should be using unlink both times

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP recursive delete function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685134/php-recursive-delete-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete a full folder in one call. You should do it recursively:

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
    foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) {
        if(is_dir($file))
            rrmdir($file);
        else
            unlink($file);
    }
    rmdir($dir);
}
```

Comment: He is not trying to delete a full folder all in one call. While a bit of recursion wouldn't be a bad thing, he was doing a depth-1 scan and deleting from there.

And no, the updated version won't work because now you are trying to call rmdir on a non-empty folder.

Comment: @kingcoyote You able to provide any light?